# Flush DNS cache on mac not working

Tags: dns, osx-yosemite

I have setup a github pages repo and linked my custom domain to the pages site.

When I open the custom domain mrmtech.co.za on another mac I get the site that I'm looking for. However on my mac it does not resolve. I have tried the following:

- Waited more than 12 hours. No difference.
- `$ nslookup mrmtech.co.za` -> gives `server can't find mrmtech.co.za: NXDOMAIN`
- `host mrmtech.co.za  8.8.8.8` -> gives `mrmtech.co.za has address 192.30.252.154, mrmtech.co.za has address 192.30.252.153` which is the correct IPs
- https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/mrmtech.co.za gives the correct IPs

Thus the settings is correct, so I tried flushing my DNS cash on the mac but with no luck. I'm running OSX 10.10.5. I have tried `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder` but no luck.

Are there other ways to flush this cache and should I also flush it in chrome somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I see that the negative TTL value for mrmtech.co.za is 1 day, and the TTL on both A records is 10 **seconds**....  ok, two questions, no three questions:

1) What is the name server your mac is using (`scutil --dns`) ?  Is it different from that other mac? (I'm sure it is)

2) Why did you try to connect to mrmtech.co.za before it was live in DNS?  Did you get it published and resolving with `host` or another external check site (whatsmydns.net) from your mac before trying it on that other mac?

3) Has this situation resolved itself now that the NXDOMAIN negative cached answer on the name server your mac uses has expired (1 day)?

I see this sequence of events all the time...  it's so common it should be in a FAQ somewhere.